# wp + not able to install updates

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, plugins, amazon-ec2

I am trying to update my `wordpress` site `plugins` and themes but I am not able to update them. I am getting below message.

> An error occurred while updating All In One WP Security: The update
>   cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This
>   is usually due to inconsistent file permissions. languages,
>   wp-security.php..... so on errors of plugins updates.

What I have tried is

1. set permission of file and folders by the following commands

   ```
   find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

   find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

   chmod -R 777 /var/www/html//wp-content/cache/autoptimize
   ```
2. run below code for setting permissions

   ```
   function AllDirChmod( $dir = "./", $dirModes = 0755, $fileModes = 0644 ){
      $d = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir );
      foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $d, 1 ) as $path ){
         if( $path->isDir() ) chmod( $path, $dirModes );
         else if( is_file( $path ) ) chmod( $path, $fileModes );
     }
   }
   ```
3. added below code in wp-config file because wp asking for `FTP` details when installing or updating anything.

   ```
   define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
   ```

My site is on `AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 with php7` server.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make your web server as the owner of your project directory. Use the following command if you are using apache:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/
```